# Matplotlib imshow displays blank plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I figured this should be simple but I guess not.

```
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = misc.imread("Alyson.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

It draws a blank canvas. Inspecting the array the values were obviously loaded correctly. I don't really know what the issue could be. I've also tried loading it with matplotlib.image.imread and with PIL.Image.open to the same effect.

I'm running Lubuntu 13.04. Here are some versions of various libraries:

```
Pillow==2.5.2
matplotlib==1.3.1
numpy==1.8.2
scipy==0.14.0
```

**EDIT: SOLVED!**
I switched the rendering backend using matplotlib.use("WX").

Comment: I have Pillow installed. Will update main post with some versions of things I have.

Comment: I tried with the misc.lena() image with no luck either.

Comment: Can you try plotting using a different backend? (See [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for details on how to change it.)

Comment: Switching to the WX backend seems to have done it. Thanks Ffisegydd :)

Comment: You should post that as a self-answer so people can easily see in the future that the question actually has an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what the cause of the problem was, but I switched the backend to wxPython and images loaded with misc.imread or matplotlib.image.imread worked fine.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WX")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...etc
```

Comment: unfortunately, wx works only with Python 2.7 for now. https://www.wxpython.org/download.php#msw